# Computer crashes and glitches when gaming (laptop)

Tags: laptop, gaming

I have been experiencing problems with my laptop whenever I play League of Legends - it tends to crash and create a buzzing sound that would hang up the computer. I could only turn off the computer and restart it again. No BSOD. It's quite strange as I play with other games and it rarely happens.

When it hangs - the screen looks like:

[image]

What could be the cause of this?

Tech specs:
Intel core i7-3630QM @ 2.4 Ghz
RAM: 8.00 GB
Windows 7 64-bit

UPDATE:
I tried playing again and this time a BSOD appeared after the screen shutdown and error prompt after restart 
[image: BSOD ERROR]
[image: ERROR]
[image: ERROR]
[image: ERROR]

Comment: I would bet on graphics - try to update drivers, undust laptop... Are you monitoring temperatures?

Comment: All the symptoms of a GPU over-heat, or under-power. On a lappy, overheat would be prime suspect. Time to get it cleaned properly.

Comment: @g2mk using speedfan and gpu-z the gpu temperature ranges from 50-70 celsius same with cores 0-3. Would you recommend getting it professionally cleaned or do it at home?

Comment: @jonathan17 It depends on: guarantee, you skills, availability of laptop service manual... Dismantling is easier than **proper** reassembling! You should try to log temperatures (SpeedFan) to files and try to tie high temperatures with laptop hang times first. Enable/look for mini-dumps (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315263) and try to interpret them. Be aware that even when you clean-up and exchange thermal grease problems may remain.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a problem with your graphics card. Try updating the graphics card driver and if that doesn't work, make sure that your laptop is getting enough airflow through the fans and it is not overheating. If the graphics card is overheating, it may crash your graphics driver or cause your computer to freeze while under load — for example, when playing demanding 3D games like in your case. If the fans are receiving adequate airflow then try opening your laptop up and cleaning out any dust, and you could even try a laptop cooling pad to place your laptop on while gaming.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other comments, this could actually be a fault with your RAM, assuming you are using the Intel video graphics, as the system and video memory may be shared.

Best bet is to run something like Memtest86+ and see if this proves any RAM faults. If not, try something like Furmark to see if you can easily replicate the issue.

Once you've determined the issue can be replicated easily, try updating your graphics driver. Assuming you don't have dedicated graphics in your machine, you will find this from the Intel website (although you may need to force a manual installation of the graphics driver, often it will tell you that you should only use a driver distributed by your machine manufacturer - these are often seriously out of date. You can find steps to do this here:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005474.html

The steps are pretty much the same for Windows 7/8/10)

If this hasn't helped, check your temps (GPU-Z and CoreTemp). If your temps are getting very hot (>75-80 c), check the vents aren't blocked with dust and clean them. Often with older machines the dust and hair can form a thick carpet across the fins of the heatsink which will likely require disassembly to remove.

If none of these are to blame, your graphics card (and if that's onboard, your CPU) are probably FUBAR.

Comment: yes I have a dedicated graphics card nvidia geforce 610M, I've already updated the driver but to no avail. Would try to run Memtest86+ soon. I've used Speedfan and gpu and cores tend to get hot at that range and doesn't cooldown. I also tried to log using gpu-z when the crash happened but I don't know how to interpret the log file.

Comment: I believe that model uses it's own dedicated memory. As such, RAM isn't likely to be at fault, but it's well worth running a memory test anyway just in case. Try running something like Furmark to see if you can reproduce the problem. It's possible the 210M has failed. If so, your only real chance of getting further life from the machine would be, and it sounds counter intuitive, to uninstall the Nvidia driver and disable the card, or at least set the default graphics processor to be your Intel HD Graphics. Will be slightly slower, but hopefully display no corruption.